# Finding the 2nd most expensive total products in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm working on simple queries to learn MySQL, in my example database, I keep track of Stores which sells electronic devices, I have a table Sells(Store, Item, Price).

And example data is,

```
'Best Buy', 'Galaxy S', 1000 
'Buy More', 'Macbook Air', 2000 
'Best Buy', 'Microsoft Mouse', 20 
'Best Buy', 'Macbook Pro Cover', 40 
'Buy More', 'Asus Zenbook', 2000
```

And so on..

I tried the following sql statement, but it says:

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function   0.000 sec

```
SELECT store
FROM sells
WHERE SUM(price) <
        (SELECT SUM(price) AS total
        FROM sells
        GROUP BY store
        ORDER BY total DESC
        LIMIT 1) 
GROUP BY store
ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC
```

I would be appreciate if you can help me

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand, you just want to sum all prices for a store, not caring about the actual products sold?

Comment: Be careful, the query you came up with only seems to work, next time you execute it, the results can be different. However, your problem is similar to the common greatest-n-per-group problem, but not quite.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, I just want to sum all prices for each store, and then rank them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will just plain show the second most expensive store;

```
SELECT STORE 
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY STORE
ORDER BY SUM(PRICE) DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/182c9/1).

If you want the price displayed too, you can just select that too;

```
SELECT STORE, SUM(PRICE) TOTAL_PRICE
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY STORE
ORDER BY TOTAL_PRICE DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/182c9/4).

Edit: If you have several most expensive stores and several second most expensive stores, the query to get the all the second most expensive ones becomes quite a bit more convoluted; I'm sure someone can beat the efficiency of this one;

```
SELECT STORE, SUM(PRICE) TOTAL_PRICE
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY STORE
HAVING TOTAL_PRICE =
  (SELECT SUM(PRICE) TMP 
   FROM TABLE_A 
   GROUP BY STORE
   HAVING TMP <
     (SELECT SUM(PRICE) TMP2
      FROM TABLE_A
      GROUP BY STORE
      ORDER BY TMP2 DESC
      LIMIT 1)
   ORDER BY TMP DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1eb88/6).

Comment: Firstly thanks ! What does LIMIT 1,1 do ? I was trying to write another subquery which's total is the maximum of the total but smaller than the maximum one

Comment: @CanCeylan LIMIT x,y means skip the first x lines (the x most expensive ones) and return the y next. In other words, in this case, skip the most expensive store, and return the second most expensive one.

Comment: But in that case, for example if I have 2 stores with equal totals, I won't get two of them right ?

Comment: @CanCeylan No, to get all if there are many, you'll need a somewhat more complex query, this was as simple as possible for the purpose. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's why I tried to use the subquerry to use "<=" in the where statement, but I think I should have used in HAVING clause ?

Comment: @CanCeylan So if there are two stores with price 4000 and two with 3999, you want the two 3999 ones?

Comment: Yes, I want every store which's total is the 2nd maximum one

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this;

```
SELECT *,
SUM(price) AS totalprice
FROM sells
GROUP BY store 
ORDER BY totalprice DESC
LIMIT 2
```

You first select the sum of the prices and store it temporarily in for ex. totalprice then as you already did group by store. To get the most expensive stores order the sum backwards and then limit to just two results.

You will be able to get the totalprice just as an ordinary column when you loop out the results

Answer (score 1):

almost correct,

```
  SELECT SUM(price) as price_total FROM sells GROUP BY store
```

if you want to order by you can do subquery, like:

```
   SELECT price_total FROM (SELECT SUM(price) as price_total FROM sells GROUP BY store) as res ORDER BY price LIMIT 2
```

if you want to take 2nd you might make another query but i think it is better to use your back-end language

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT distinct price from sells ORDER BY price DESC`, and in your code, just take the second one.

If you need the rest of the info, do this:

```
SELECT * from sells
WHERE price = (SELECT distinct price from sells ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

didn'T test it but should work

```
SELECT S.store
FROM (
SELECT SUM(T.price) AS sum_price
FROM formList_Total AS T
GROUP BY  T.store
) AS S
ORDER BY sum_price DESC 
LIMIT 1 , 1
```

Sorry, went to testing, here what i ended up with.

Comment: But I want to sum all of the prices for each store, how are you calculating the sumation of them ?

Comment: It says, "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY store"